# How to check if a route or its nested route is active?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, react-router-dom

For example there are the following routes:

```js
<Routes>
  <Route path="admin">
    <Route path="users">
      <Route index element={<UserList />} />
      <Route path="create" element={<UserDetails />} />
      <Route path=":id" element={<UserDetails readOnly />} />
      <Route path=":id/edit" element={<UserDetails />} />
    </Route>
    <Route path="roles">
      <Route index element={<RoleList />} />
      <Route path="create" element={<RoleDetails />} />
      <Route path=":id" element={<RoleDetails readOnly />} />
      <Route path=":id/edit" element={<RoleDetails />} />
    </Route>
  </Route>
  <Route path="about" />
</Routes>
```

If the current route is `/admin/users/123` then `/admin` and `/admin/users` links are active. It works fine. But I need to determine whether a link is active manually:

```js
import { ExpandMore } from '@mui/icons-material';
import { ButtonBase, IconButton } from '@mui/material';
import cx from 'classnames';
import { NavLink, To, useMatch } from 'react-router-dom';

interface NavButtonProps {
  name: string;
  to: To;
}

export function NavButton(props: NavButtonProps) {
  const match = useMatch(props.to as string); // What pattern to use here?
  const active = Boolean(match);
  return (
    <ButtonBase component="div" className={cx({ active })}>
      <NavLink to={props.to}>
        {props.name}
      </NavLink>
      <IconButton onClick={openMenuWithLinksToNestedRoutes}>
        <ExpandMore />
      </IconButton>
    </ButtonBase>
  );
}
```

How to do it? What pattern should I use? For sure I can see a source code of `NavLink` component:

```js
export const NavLink = React.forwardRef<HTMLAnchorElement, NavLinkProps>(
  function NavLinkWithRef(
    {
      "aria-current": ariaCurrentProp = "page",
      caseSensitive = false,
      className: classNameProp = "",
      end = false,
      style: styleProp,
      to,
      children,
      ...rest
    },
    ref
  ) {
    let path = useResolvedPath(to, { relative: rest.relative });
    let location = useLocation();
    let routerState = React.useContext(DataRouterStateContext);
    let { navigator } = React.useContext(NavigationContext);

    let toPathname = navigator.encodeLocation
      ? navigator.encodeLocation(path).pathname
      : path.pathname;
    let locationPathname = location.pathname;
    let nextLocationPathname =
      routerState && routerState.navigation && routerState.navigation.location
        ? routerState.navigation.location.pathname
        : null;

    if (!caseSensitive) {
      locationPathname = locationPathname.toLowerCase();
      nextLocationPathname = nextLocationPathname
        ? nextLocationPathname.toLowerCase()
        : null;
      toPathname = toPathname.toLowerCase();
    }

    let isActive =
      locationPathname === toPathname ||
      (!end &&
        locationPathname.startsWith(toPathname) &&
        locationPathname.charAt(toPathname.length) === "/");
```

But it's really complicated. I think there should be an easier way.

Comment: What, or why, do you need to know a specific route is active outside what RRD already handles? Can you clarify the use case, e.g. what you are trying to do and what the issue/problem is that you are trying to solve for? You just want to know if the `NavLink` is active so you can pass something to the `Button` component? Does the `Button` need to wrap the `NavLink` component?

Comment: I need to create a custom component `NavButton` that wraps `NavLink` and adds some extra functionality to it. For instance it will have an expand button that will show a popup menu with links to nested routes. And I need to highlight that expand button if the current link or any of links to nested routes are active. I updated the `NavButton` component in the question to demonstrate the idea

Comment: I need to wrap `NavLink` using `ButtonBase`, because I need a link to look like a MUI button. MUI adds some styles and a ripple effect to `ButtonBase`. And also I need to add an expand button for a submenu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could let the `NavLink` continue doing the work of knowing when it is active and "leak" out to the outer component scope when it is. `NavLink` has available to it a `children` render function prop that is passed an `isActive` prop. The following using a React ref may work for your needs.

```
export function NavButton(props: NavButtonProps) {
  const isActiveRef = React.useRef(false);

  return (
    <ButtonBase
      component="div"
      className={cx({ active: isActiveRef.current })}
    >
      <NavLink to={props.to}>
        {({ isActive }) => {
          isActiveRef.current = isActive;
          return props.name;
        }}
      </NavLink>
      <IconButton onClick={openMenuWithLinksToNestedRoutes}>
        <ExpandMore />
      </IconButton>
    </ButtonBase>
  );
}
```

An alternative is to use a local state in `NavButton` and create a "child" component that can pass out the `isActive` status via a `useEffect` hook.

```
const Label = ({ setActive, isActive, name }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    setActive(isActive);
  }, [isActive, setActive]);

  return name;
};

export function NavButton(props: NavButtonProps) {
  const [active, setActive] = React.useState(false);

  return (
    <ButtonBase component="div" className={cx({ active })}>
      <NavLink to={props.to}>
        {({ isActive }) => (
          <Label
            name={props.name}
            isActive={isActive}
            setActive={setActive}
          />
        )}
      </NavLink>
      <IconButton onClick={openMenuWithLinksToNestedRoutes}>
        <ExpandMore />
      </IconButton>
    </ButtonBase>
  );
}
```